# Split the large list into sub-list and apply the executors for parallel executio of sub-list using java

Tags: java

I want to execute the large size list. its take too much time get the values. so i divided list as sublist then I want to run the all list parallelly.
can we give some suggestion for that.

Example :
Employee Class :

```
public class Employee {

private int eno;
private String ename;
private String desg;

public Employee(int eno, String ename, String desg) {
    this.eno = eno;
    this.ename = ename;
    this.desg = desg;
}

public int getEno() {
    return eno;
}

public void setEno(int eno) {
    this.eno = eno;
}

public String getEname() {
    return ename;
}

public void setEname(String ename) {
    this.ename = ename;
}

public String getDesg() {
    return desg;
}

public void setDesg(String desg) {
    this.desg = desg;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
 */
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "{eno=" + eno + ", ename=" + ename + ", desg=" + desg + "}";
  }
 }
```

Add Employees using below class :
Actually i am getting those values from webservices. sample i created below class

```
public class EmployeeTest  {

  public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
    List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 701; i++) {
        employees.add(new Employee(i, "s" + i, "sd" + i));
    }
    return employees;
  }
}
```

I called list of employees and create sub-list each sub-list contain 100.
I want to execute all sub-list parallel. Here I am getting 
      `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException` because of 702 element not there.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    List<Employee> collect =  new EmployeeTest().getEmployees().parallelStream().collect(Collectors.toList());
    int partitionSize = 100;
    List<List<Employee>> partitions = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < collect.size();i += partitionSize){
        partitions.add(collect.subList(i,i + Math.min(partitionSize, collect.size() - i)));
    }

    for (List<Employee> list : partitions) {
        System.out.println(list.get(1));
    }
}
```

how should i overcome this kind of error and how should i implements executors here for parallel execution of all list.

output :

```
   {eno=2, ename=s2, desg=sd2}
   {eno=102, ename=s102, desg=sd102}
   {eno=202, ename=s202, desg=sd202}
   {eno=302, ename=s302, desg=sd302}
   {eno=402, ename=s402, desg=sd402}
   {eno=502, ename=s502, desg=sd502}
   {eno=602, ename=s602, desg=sd602}
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:1202)
at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.get(ArrayList.java:1019)
at com.employee.ExecuteServicesDemo.main(ExecuteServicesDemo.java:22)
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

The exception you get is because in your last loop you are accessing the second element of each list with `list.get(1)`, which is not present in the last list (it contains only one element). Remember that index of a list is 0-based. So if you change it to `list.get(0)`, your code will run just fine.

To process this lists in separate threads you can do something like this:

```
ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(parts.size());
for (List<Employee> list : partitions) {
    exec.submit(() -> { // process the list here });
}
```

If using java version < 8 then you have to use anonymous class instead of lambda:

```
exec.submit(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // process here
    }
});
```

Also note that `submit` returns a Future which stores the result of concurrent computation, so you can store it in a variable:

```
Future<YourAnyType> res = exec.submit(() -> {
     // process
     // return value of YourAnyType
});
```

Please note that in this case the lambda is an implementation of a `Callable<T>` interface.